# Read textfile line by line and save certain values in an array

Tags: vba, excel, readfile

I'm stuck at the moment with this problem... I have following textfile format (is from an email and should be automatically read into excel each week).:

```
TextTextText
Text
TextText
TextTextText

2/2  2/3  2/4  2/5  2/6
63 61  65  67  62 
59 51  45  11  20

11 22  41  32  55

TextTextText
Text
TextText
TextTextText
```

And I ONLY  need basically the last column of the data. So the data for the 2/6. Now how do I extract that? Split doesn't work for the number rows, since they have different spaces in between (2 between the first 2, three thereafter). The text at the beginning can be of different length. However there are always! 35 data rows.

My questions are basically:
1. How would you recognize if it's a data row or not?
2. How would you split the data lines correctly?

This is what I've got so far...

```
Sub ReadFile()
    Dim FSO As FileSystemObject
    Dim FSOFile As File
    Dim FSOStream As TextStream

    Dim aintData(35, 1) As Integer

    Set FSO = New FileSystemObject
    Set FSOFile = FSO.GetFile("C:\users\mp\Desktop\Test.txt")
    Set FSOStream = FSOFile.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading, TristateUseDefault)
    Do While Not FSOStream.AtEndOfStream
        Debug.Print FSOStream.ReadLine
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: You can use the replace function to replace a space by, for instance, a "#" and then use split and trim.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim oFSO As Object
    Dim varText As Variant
    Dim arrText() As String
    Dim strLine As String
    Dim strResult As String
    Dim strFilePath As String

    strFilePath = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files, *.txt")
    If strFilePath = "False" Then Exit Sub  'Pressed cancel

    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    arrText = Split(oFSO.OpenTextFile(strFilePath).ReadAll, vbCrLf)

    For Each varText In arrText
        strLine = Application.Trim(varText)
        If IsNumeric(Left(strLine, 1)) Then strResult = strResult & vbCrLf & Trim(Right(Replace(strLine, " ", String(255, " ")), 255))
    Next varText

    If Len(strResult) > 0 Then
        strResult = Mid(strResult, Len(vbCrLf) + 1)

        'At this point strResult contains the data you want
        'I have used a MsgBox to verify
        'However, you could output the data in any way you see fit
        MsgBox strResult

        'To put the result in an array, simply re-purpose arrText:
        arrText = Split(strResult, vbCrLf)
        MsgBox Join(arrText, vbCrLf)  'Again, I used a MsgBox to test its output
    Else
        MsgBox "No data found"
    End If

End Sub
```